# Want to make my user's supplied text input safe to display in the chatbox (strip all html and xss exploits)

Tags: php

I want to strip all html and cross site scripting exploits from the user supplied input, since all the input that is supplied by the user is then displayed in the chat box to other users.

I plan to run the supplied input through a filter such as htmlpurifier before I insert it in the database, and then each subsequent database read doesn't have to filter it.

htmlpurifier seems overkill but maybe necessary to ensure no cross site scripting exploits are used? However even with that filter I can't see a way to strip things such as:

```
<img src="http://example.com" />
```

From the input.

Is there a tool/class/function that can do what I want? (strip all html and remove XSS exploits) Bearing in mind this is only for a chatbox not the whole site, but it does need to be fast as the chatbox has many simultaneous users.

Thanks.

Comment: `<img src="javascript:…" />` is an XSS attack vector.

Comment: just html encode the output

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to accomplish this and without seeing code its not really possible to give specific examples, but check out things like [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php), [preg_match](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), [preg_filter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-filter.php), [htmlspecailchars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php), this could go on for a while so read through [php string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php), and [PCRE](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php).

Also when posting stuff to DB there are DB drivers pre built to do this.  Check out  [PHP data objects](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), or [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).  In my opinion you should focus on PHP data objects as its tends to be a little easier to keep things secure.